# How can I save the FREQUENCIES of one variable as a new variable in SPSS?

Tags: frequency, repeat, spss, measure

I've got a DataSet with repeated measures. Now I want to know how many measures I've got for each participant. I kind of get the information by using the FREQUENCIES command on the Participant_ID variable. But I actually want to know the frequencies of the frequencies of Participant_ID so that I can make statements like "5 Participants replied 38 times, 60 participants replied 39 times...."

So is there a way to save the frequencies as a new variable (so that I can use the FREQUENCIES command on it)? 
Or is there another way to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that information as a new variable in the main dataset or as a separate dataset by using AGGREGATE (Data > Aggregate) and choosing Number of Cases as the statistic with Participant_ID as the break variable.

In general, although Aggregate is simpler here, you can use OMS (the Output Management System) to save any table as a dataset.  See Utilities > OMS Control Panel for more information.